# countably additive measure and convergence.

Tags: measure-theory

If a countable sequence of sets $A_i \subseteq X$ converges to a set $A \subseteq X$. I would like to show that for a non-negative countably additive function $\mu$ on $X$, that $\mu(A_i)$ converges to $\mu(A)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "$A_i$ converge to $A$"?

Comment: Yes. I meant to ask in the question what this might be referring to. Possibly meaning that A is the union of $A_i's$. Where the $A_i$'s are increasing. But I'm new to this, so I am not sure.

Comment: @rustyracketman: What textbook are you using? It would seem the inferred meaning is the union of the sets, but it's reasonable to ask if you have a precise definition.

Comment: @Clayton. It is just a lecturers notes. No precise definition is given. I think it is probably assumed I have covered this already.

Comment: Okay. no worries. I have figured this out now. (well for the case of unions of sets). If there is a more general case, then please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

Another meaning for $A_n$ converges to $A$ might be:
$$
A = \limsup A_n = \liminf A_n
$$
That is,
$$
A = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=k}^\infty A_n
=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n=k}^\infty A_n
$$

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, you want to show:

> If $A_n \uparrow A$, where $A \in \mathcal {A}$ and $A_n \in \mathcal{A}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\mu(A_n) \uparrow \mu(A)$.

*Proof*. Sequence $\{\mu(A_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is growing on becase $\mu$ is countably additive  measure. So, if $\mu(A_n)=+\infty$ for some $n$, then $\mu(A)=+\infty$ and $\mu(A_m)=+\infty$ for all $m \ge n,$ so in this case the statement true. If $\mu(A_n)<+\infty$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then using countably additive and decomposition $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \bigsqcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_n \backslash \bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1} A_k)= \bigsqcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_n \backslash A_{n-1})$, where $A_0 = \emptyset$, which give us $$\begin{align}\mu(A)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n \backslash A_{n-1})&=\lim_{n\to +\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} [\mu(A_k)-\mu(A_{k-1})]\\&=\lim_{n \to +\infty} [\mu(A_n)-\mu(A_0)]\\&=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \mu(A_n).\end{align}$$

Notation: $A_n \uparrow A$ means that $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is sequence of sets such that $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}A_n = A,$ where $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n.$ You can prove this using definition $$\liminf_{n\to \infty}A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k \quad \text{and} \quad \limsup_{n\to \infty}A_n=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$$ If this two sets are equal, then we say that sequnce $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges and their common value is called limit of sequence sets and we denote it with $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}A_n(=\liminf_{n\to \infty}A_n=\limsup_{n\to \infty}A_n)$. 
We all this work in some algebra $\mathcal{A}$.

You can show for homework that

> If $A_n \downarrow A$, where $A_n \in \mathcal{A}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\mu(A_1) <+\infty$ then $\mu(A_n) \downarrow \mu(A)$

Here $A_n \downarrow A$ denotes that $A_{n+1} \subset A_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N},$ and if $A=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ then (prove it) $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} A_n = A.$